Unit test for Mediator with Generic Handler
using AutoMapper;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Commands.Abstract;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Models;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Persistence;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Commands.PaymentPlan.Create;
public class CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandler : CreateRequestHandler<PaymentPlanModel, Domain.PaymentPlan>
{
    public CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandler(
        ILogger<CreateRequest<PaymentPlanModel>> logger,
        FinanceDbContext dbContext,
        IMapper mapper
    ) : base(logger, dbContext, mapper)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<PaymentPlanModel> Handle(CreateRequest<PaymentPlanModel> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Create(request, DbContext.PaymentPlans, cancellationToken);
    }
}


using AutoMapper;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Common;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Persistence;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Commands.Abstract;

public abstract class CreateRequestHandler<TModel, TEntity> : RequestHandler<CreateRequest<TModel>, TModel, FinanceDbContext> where TEntity : class
{
    protected CreateRequestHandler(
        ILogger<CreateRequest<TModel>> logger,
        FinanceDbContext dbContext,
        IMapper mapper
    ) : base(
        logger,
        dbContext,
        mapper
    ) { }

    public async Task<TModel> Create(CreateRequest<TModel> request, DbSet<TEntity> table, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Convert the request payload into an entity.
        var mappedEntity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(request.Model);

        // Add the entity to the DB context.
        var entry = table.Add(mappedEntity);

        // Save the DB context changes.
        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        // Map the saved entity back to a model and return it.
        return Mapper.Map<TModel>(entry.Entity);
    }
}

I am trying to create Unit test for the Above CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandler
using AutoMapper;
using End.Microservice.Core.Infrastructure.Services.Interfaces;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Commands.Abstract;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Commands.PaymentPlan.Create;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Commands.PaymentPlan.Patch;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Application.Models;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Config.Settings;
using End.Microservice.Financing.Persistence;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Moq;

namespace End.Microservice.Financing.Tests.Application.Commands.PaymentPlan.Create
{
    public class CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandlerTests
    {
        private readonly CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandler _handler;
        private readonly Mock<ILogger<CreateRequest<PaymentPlanModel>>> _loggerMock;
        private readonly Mock<FinanceDbContext> _dbContextMock;
        private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapperMock;
        private readonly CreateRequest<PaymentPlanModel> _request;

        private Mock<DbContextOptions<FinanceDbContext>> _dbcontextoptions;
        private Mock<IOptionsSnapshot<Settings>> _optionSettings;
        private new Mock<ITimeService> _timeService;
        private Mock<IUserService> _userService;
        private Mock<IMediator> _mediator;
        private Mock<IHashService> _hashservice;

        public CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandlerTests()
        {
            _dbcontextoptions = new Mock<DbContextOptions<FinanceDbContext>>();
            _optionSettings = new Mock<IOptionsSnapshot<Settings>>();
            _timeService = new Mock<ITimeService>();
            _userService = new Mock<IUserService>();
            _mediator = new Mock<IMediator>();
            _hashservice = new Mock<IHashService>();
            _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<CreateRequest<PaymentPlanModel>>>();
            _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();

            var settings = new Settings
            {
                Version = "1.0",
                Environment = "Development", 
                ConnectionStrings = new ConnectionStringsSettings
                {
                    Finance = "MyConnectionString"
                }
            };
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FinanceDbContext>()
                           .Options;

            var settingsOptions = Options.Create(settings);

            var settingsSnapshotMock = new Mock<IOptionsSnapshot<Settings>>();
            settingsSnapshotMock.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns(settings);

            _dbContextMock = new Mock<FinanceDbContext>(options, settingsSnapshotMock.Object, _timeService.Object, _userService.Object
                , _mediator.Object, _hashservice.Object);

            _handler = new CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandler(
                _loggerMock.Object,
                _dbContextMock.Object,
                _mapperMock.Object
            );

            _request = new CreateRequest<PaymentPlanModel>
            {
                Model = new PaymentPlanModel()
                {
                    Account = "1234567890",
                    PolicyNumber = "111",
                    PolicyPaymentAmount = 20,
                    PolicyCity = "Thrissur",
                    PolicyCompany = "xyz",
                    PolicyCountryCode = "2",
                    PolicyEmail = "xyz@gmail.com",
                    PolicyFirstName = "ash",
                    PolicyLastName = "involvz",
                    PolicyPhone = "9562019393",
                    PolicyPostalCode = "680517",
                    PolicyStateCode = "2",
                    PolicyStreet = "kunnamkulam",
                    ContractAdminCost = 10,
                    ContractSellingAgentId = 4,
                    ContractAdministratorId = 3,
                    ContractDownPayment = 1,
                    ContractId = "2",
                    ContractStatusId = 1,
                    ContractTotalSalePrice = 20,
                    FinanceFee = 20,
                    LastPaymentPlanAtemptDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    LastPaymentPlanAttemptResultId = 1,
                    LastPaymentPlanAdjustmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    LastPaymentPlanAdjustmentTypeId = 1,
                    NextPaymentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    NumberOfDeferredPayments = 1,
                    NumberOfDueDateChanges = 1,
                    NumberOfLateFeesWaived = 1,
                    NumberOfLateFeesAssesses = 1,
                    NumberOfNSFFeesAssesses = 1,
                    NumberOfNSFFeesWaived = 1,
                    NumberOfReinstatements = 1,
                    NextPaymentId = 1,
                    NextPaymentReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                    Occurrences = 1,
                    PaymentMethodId = 10,
                    PaymentPlanAdjustmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                    PaymentPlanAdjustmentTypeId = 1,
                    PaymentPlanTotalAmount = 20,
                    PaymentPlanBalance = 10,
                    PaymentPlanBillingFrequencyId = 1,
                    PaymentPlanCancelDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                    PaymentPlanCancelReasonId = 0,
                    PaymentPlanDefunded = true,
                    PaymentPlanDefundedAdmin = 1,
                    PaymentPlanDefundedAgent = 1,
                    PaymentPlanFundedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                    PaymentPlanFunded = true,
                    PaymentPlanFundedAdmin = 1,
                    PaymentPlanFundedAgent = 1,
                    PaymentPlanNumber = 1,
                    PaymentPlanPendingCancelDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                    PaymentPlanStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                    PaymentPlanStatus = 1,
                    PaymentPlanTotalLateFees = 1,
                    PaymentPlanTotalNSFFees = 1,
                    PaymentsMade = 10,
                    PaymentsRemaining = 2,
                    PaymentProcessDay = 2,
                    ProductSoldId = 1,
                    SecondaryContactEmail = "xyy@gmail.com",
                    SecondaryContactFirstName = "xy",
                    SecondaryContactLastName = "yy",
                    SecondaryContactPhone = "9447772010",
                    TotalDiscountsApplied = 2,
                    PaymentPlanTerm = 2
                }
            };
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Handle_ValidRequest_ReturnsCreatedPaymentPlan()
        {
            // Arrange
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            var paymentPlanEntity = new Domain.PaymentPlan();
            var savedPaymentPlanEntity = new Domain.PaymentPlan
            {
                Id = 1,
                Account = "1234567890",
                PolicyNumber = "111",
                PolicyPaymentAmount = 20,
                PolicyCity = "Thrissur",
                PolicyCompany = "xyz",
                PolicyCountryCode = "2",
                PolicyEmail = "xyz@gmail.com",
                PolicyFirstName = "ash",
                PolicyLastName = "involvz",
                PolicyPhone = "9562019393",
                PolicyPostalCode = "680517",
                PolicyStateCode = "2",
                PolicyStreet = "kunnamkulam",
                ContractAdminCost = 10,
                ContractSellingAgentId = 4,
                ContractAdministratorId = 3,
                ContractDownPayment = 1,
                ContractId = "2",
                ContractStatusId = 1,
                ContractTotalSalePrice = 20,
                FinanceFee = 20,
                LastPaymentPlanAtemptDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                LastPaymentPlanAttemptResultId = 1,
                LastPaymentPlanAdjustmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                LastPaymentPlanAdjustmentTypeId = 1,
                NextPaymentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                NumberOfDeferredPayments = 1,
                NumberOfDueDateChanges = 1,
                NumberOfLateFeesWaived = 1,
                NumberOfLateFeesAssesses = 1,
                NumberOfNSFFeesAssesses = 1,
                NumberOfNSFFeesWaived = 1,
                NumberOfReinstatements = 1,
                NextPaymentId = 1,
                NextPaymentReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                Occurrences = 1,
                PaymentMethodId = 10,
                PaymentPlanAdjustmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanAdjustmentTypeId = 1,
                PaymentPlanTotalAmount = 20,
                PaymentPlanBalance = 10,
                PaymentPlanBillingFrequencyId = 1,
                PaymentPlanCancelDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanCancelReasonId = 0,
                PaymentPlanDefunded = true,
                PaymentPlanDefundedAdmin = 1,
                PaymentPlanDefundedAgent = 1,
                PaymentPlanFundedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanFunded = true,
                PaymentPlanFundedAdmin = 1,
                PaymentPlanFundedAgent = 1,
                PaymentPlanNumber = 1,
                PaymentPlanPendingCancelDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanStatus = 1,
                PaymentPlanTotalLateFees = 1,
                PaymentPlanTotalNSFFees = 1,
                PaymentsMade = 10,
                PaymentsRemaining = 2,
                PaymentProcessDay = 2,
                ProductSoldId = 1,
                SecondaryContactEmail = "xyy@gmail.com",
                SecondaryContactFirstName = "xy",
                SecondaryContactLastName = "yy",
                SecondaryContactPhone = "9447772010",
                TotalDiscountsApplied = 2,
                PaymentPlanTerm = 2
            };
            var savedPaymentPlanModel = new PaymentPlanModel
            {
                Account = "1234567890",
                PolicyNumber = "111",
                PolicyPaymentAmount = 20,
                PolicyCity = "Thrissur",
                PolicyCompany = "xyz",
                PolicyCountryCode = "2",
                PolicyEmail = "xyz@gmail.com",
                PolicyFirstName = "ash",
                PolicyLastName = "involvz",
                PolicyPhone = "9562019393",
                PolicyPostalCode = "680517",
                PolicyStateCode = "2",
                PolicyStreet = "kunnamkulam",
                ContractAdminCost = 10,
                ContractSellingAgentId = 4,
                ContractAdministratorId = 3,
                ContractDownPayment = 1,
                ContractId = "2",
                ContractStatusId = 1,
                ContractTotalSalePrice = 20,
                FinanceFee = 20,
                LastPaymentPlanAtemptDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                LastPaymentPlanAttemptResultId = 1,
                LastPaymentPlanAdjustmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                LastPaymentPlanAdjustmentTypeId = 1,
                NextPaymentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                NumberOfDeferredPayments = 1,
                NumberOfDueDateChanges = 1,
                NumberOfLateFeesWaived = 1,
                NumberOfLateFeesAssesses = 1,
                NumberOfNSFFeesAssesses = 1,
                NumberOfNSFFeesWaived = 1,
                NumberOfReinstatements = 1,
                NextPaymentId = 1,
                NextPaymentReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                Occurrences = 1,
                PaymentMethodId = 10,
                PaymentPlanAdjustmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanAdjustmentTypeId = 1,
                PaymentPlanTotalAmount = 20,
                PaymentPlanBalance = 10,
                PaymentPlanBillingFrequencyId = 1,
                PaymentPlanCancelDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanCancelReasonId = 0,
                PaymentPlanDefunded = true,
                PaymentPlanDefundedAdmin = 1,
                PaymentPlanDefundedAgent = 1,
                PaymentPlanFundedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanFunded = true,
                PaymentPlanFundedAdmin = 1,
                PaymentPlanFundedAgent = 1,
                PaymentPlanNumber = 1,
                PaymentPlanPendingCancelDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                PaymentPlanStatus = 1,
                PaymentPlanTotalLateFees = 1,
                PaymentPlanTotalNSFFees = 1,
                PaymentsMade = 10,
                PaymentsRemaining = 2,
                PaymentProcessDay = 2,
                ProductSoldId = 1,
                SecondaryContactEmail = "xyy@gmail.com",
                SecondaryContactFirstName = "xy",
                SecondaryContactLastName = "yy",
                SecondaryContactPhone = "9447772010",
                TotalDiscountsApplied = 2,
                PaymentPlanTerm = 2
            };

            var entityEntryMock = new Mock<EntityEntry<Domain.PaymentPlan>>();
            entityEntryMock.Setup(e => e.Entity).Returns(paymentPlanEntity);
            entityEntryMock.Setup(e => e.State).Returns(EntityState.Added);



            _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<Domain.PaymentPlan>(_request.Model)).Returns(paymentPlanEntity);
            _dbContextMock.Setup(db => db.PaymentPlans.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Domain.PaymentPlan>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(entityEntryMock.Object);

            _dbContextMock.Setup(db => db.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
            _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<PaymentPlanModel>(savedPaymentPlanEntity)).Returns(savedPaymentPlanModel);


            // Act
            var result = await _handler.Handle(_request, cancellationToken);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            // Add more assertions as needed
        }
    }
}

But I am getting an error on setting up AddAsync method
 End.Microservice.Financing.Tests.Application.Commands.PaymentPlan.Create.CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandlerTests.Handle_ValidRequest_ReturnsCreatedPaymentPlan
 Source: PaymentPlanUnitTests.cs line 284
 Duration: 20.3 sec
Message: 
System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry1[[End.Microservice.Financing.Domain.PaymentPlan, End.Microservice.Financing.Domain, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments') ---- System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.EntityEntry1Proxy' not found.
Stack Trace: 
ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments) ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors) CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments) line 110 Mock1.InitializeInstance() line 502
Mock1.OnGetObject() line 516 Mock.get_Object() line 180 Mock1.get_Object() line 453
CreatePaymentPlanRequestHandlerTests.Handle_ValidRequest_ReturnsCreatedPaymentPlan() line 456
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments) your text`

How about avoiding all the mocking fuzz by creating integration tests with a real (test-db)?

Can't , request from the client
